# 'writeUserData' is not defined no-undef in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and I try to create a function:

I sum up my code:

```
class Signup extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {

}

writeUserData = (userId, username, email) => {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: username,
    email: email
  });
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if(!error) {
                writeUserData(userID, username, email); //'writeUserData' is not defined  no-undef

    }
```

why my writeUserData is not defined  no-undef?

Answer (score 5):

`writeUserData` exists on class instance and you need to call it like `this.writeUserData(userID, username, email)`

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if(!error) {
            this.writeUserData(userID, username, email); 

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! but when I call the function with `this`, it gives me: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'writeUserData' of undefined

Comment: @RickJoe How is the function called. The name suggests you call it from form submit handler but the error suggest you call it from an async function.

Comment: @HMR oh, I call it inside `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is a firebase function, maybe it is async...

Comment: @RickJoe In JS it is a pita got get `this` right. So your error depends on how `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is defined (is it a class method, bound correctly or arrow function), how it's called and how the callbacks of a promise are defined (are they arrow functions). You could either post code (update question) or console log the value of `this` and see where you lose it.

Comment: @HMR createUserWithEmailAndPassword is inside the submit handler. thanks for your anwer.

Comment: The fact that you define handleSubmit as a arrow function, from where you call it doesn't matter, by any chance are you caling writeUserData from somewhere else. Also are you sure you have this.writeUserData called in handleSubmit function itself and not somewhere else.